# Get prior value of lookup and fetch its field value

Tags: trigger, workflow, process-builder, formula-field, lookup

The requirement is to get prior value of lookup field (that is parent record) and fetch its field. Is it possible via formula field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&type=5), you cannot get the previous value in a **formula field**, as it is not available there.

> This function is available only in:
>
> - Assignment rules
> - Validation rules
> - Field updates
> - Workflow rules if the evaluation criteria is set to Evaluate the rule    when a record is: created, and every time it’s edited .
> - Formula criteria for executing actions in Process Builder.